# Initialising create-react-app with a specific version of a package

Tags: npm, create-react-app

I am trying to initialise a `create-react-app` project.

Unfortunately this is failing when it attempts to fetch `webpack-dev-server@3.1.14`, as my company's internal NPM registry has decided that 3.1.14 has a vulnerability and so returns a 404.

How can I initialise `create-react-app`, and specify that it must use `webpack-dev-server@`**`3.1.13`**?

The following is the last 50 lines of the verbose output:

```
...
npm verb get http://myregistry:1234/jest not expired, no request
npm verb afterAdd c:\dev\npm-cache\eslint-plugin-react\7.11.1\package\package.json written
npm verb afterAdd c:\dev\npm-cache\jest\23.6.0\package\package.json not in flight; writing
npm verb correctMkdir c:\dev\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb cache add spec eslint@5.6.0
npm verb addNamed "5.6.0" is a plain semver version for eslint
npm verb addNameVersion registry:http://myregistry:1234/eslint not in flight; fetching
npm verb get http://myregistry:1234/eslint-plugin-flowtype not expired, no request
npm verb afterAdd c:\dev\npm-cache\jest\23.6.0\package\package.json written
npm verb afterAdd c:\dev\npm-cache\eslint-plugin-flowtype\2.50.1\package\package.json not in flight; writing
npm verb correctMkdir c:\dev\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb get http://myregistry:1234/webpack-dev-server not expired, no request
npm verb addRemoteTarball http://myregistry:1234/webpack-dev-server/-/webpack-dev-server-3.1.14.tgz not in flight; adding
npm verb addRemoteTarball [ 'http://myregistry:1234/webpack-dev-server/-/webpack-dev-server-3.1.14.tgz',
npm verb addRemoteTarball   '60fb229b997fc5a0a1fc6237421030180959d469' ]
npm verb afterAdd c:\dev\npm-cache\eslint-plugin-flowtype\2.50.1\package\package.json written
npm verb get http://myregistry:1234/babel-core not expired, no request
npm verb get http://myregistry:1234/eslint not expired, no request
npm info retry fetch attempt 1 at 9:58:55 AM
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 9:58:55 AM
npm http fetch GET http://myregistry:1234/webpack-dev-server/-/webpack-dev-server-3.1.14.tgz
npm verb afterAdd c:\dev\npm-cache\babel-core\7.0.0-bridge.0\package\package.json not in flight; writing
npm verb correctMkdir c:\dev\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb afterAdd c:\dev\npm-cache\eslint\5.6.0\package\package.json not in flight; writing
npm verb correctMkdir c:\dev\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb request uri http://myregistry:1234/webpack
npm verb request no auth needed
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 9:58:55 AM
npm verb etag "3cb43ef0e59f247dfcf5f855611d5749"
npm http request GET http://myregistry:1234/webpack
npm verb afterAdd c:\dev\npm-cache\babel-core\7.0.0-bridge.0\package\package.json written
npm http fetch 404 http://myregistry:1234/webpack-dev-server/-/webpack-dev-server-3.1.14.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://myregistry:1234/webpack-dev-server/-/webpack-dev-server-3.1.14.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 404
npm verb afterAdd c:\dev\npm-cache\eslint\5.6.0\package\package.json written
npm http 304 http://myregistry:1234/webpack
npm verb headers { 'x-powered-by': 'Sinopia/1.4.0',
npm verb headers   etag: '"3cb43ef0e59f247dfcf5f855611d5749"',
npm verb headers   'x-status-cat': 'http://flic.kr/p/aXY3dH',
npm verb headers   date: 'Tue, 22 Jan 2019 09:58:55 GMT',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive' }
npm verb etag http://myregistry:1234/webpack from cache
npm verb get saving webpack to c:\dev\npm-cache\appduv03d1.machine.test.group_4873\webpack\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir c:\dev\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb cache add spec webpack@4.19.1
npm verb addNamed "4.19.1" is a plain semver version for webpack
npm verb addNameVersion registry:http://myregistry:1234/webpack not in flight; fetching
npm verb get http://myregistry:1234/webpack not expired, no request
npm verb afterAdd c:\dev\npm-cache\webpack\4.19.1\package\package.json not in flight; writing
npm verb correctMkdir c:\dev\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb afterAdd c:\dev\npm-cache\webpack\4.19.1\package\package.json written
npm info retry fetch attempt 2 at 9:59:05 AM
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 9:59:05 AM
npm http fetch GET http://myregistry:1234/webpack-dev-server/-/webpack-dev-server-3.1.14.tgz
npm http fetch 404 http://myregistry:1234/webpack-dev-server/-/webpack-dev-server-3.1.14.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://myregistry:1234/webpack-dev-server/-/webpack-dev-server-3.1.14.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 404
```

Comment: one easy way would be to make a change in your package.json directly and specify the correct version of webpack-dev-server. Run npm install afterwards

Comment: I do not even get to the point of it creating a package.json for me to edit.

Answer (score 0):

what is the error showing

simple way:if i am getting you

1.create-react-app my-app
2.cd my-app
3.npm i webpack-dev-server@3.1.13
4.if high severity vulnerability comes in just  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

**if any dependencies are migrated or has problem within you will find the solution in terminal msg,**

Comment: I have added the console output - I hope that helps. It may not be clear from my question, but step 1 (create-react-app my-app) does not complete.

Answer (score 0):

i think it will work

$ npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org

**than clean cache**

$ npm cache clean
$ npm rebuild

or it could be proxy server issue 
try other internet connection

Comment: Unfortunately I work in a corporate environment where we are required to use the internal repository.